How to get users to scroll more on a page when the affordance of the mobile app screen does not offer so?
Users are typically not used to scrolling on certain screens on mobile apps like say a post transaction screen where the transaction is confirmed and/ or the user may be looking at delivery details. One could add signifiers on the app screen to scroll below, but I am looking for some examples of ideas which may have worked. My google search isn't leading anywhere. I may be searching incorrectly as well.
What I want to do it get users to scroll, more than would typically do on a particular screen? All the solutions linked have been deployed. But I want users to scroll more, on a page which does not offer any affordance that it is in infinite feed.

The question concerns mostly with website designs. While the principles may stay the same, the practice may vary on mobile web screens. Looking for those insights.

Why do you need them to scroll? How do you know they aren't scrolling?

It’s an old problem asked many times about with many answers and solutions over the years. Another example: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/87785/indicating-the-presence-of-content-below-the-fold-in-a-mobile-ui/87786#87786
